# How to git archive an untracked directory?

Tags: git

I have a CI process that runs a `build` process on my application which does things like minimizing code, obscufating etc and it outputs the result into a `/build` folder within my project.

I have added the `/build` path to my .gitignore to avoid duplication of code in the repository.

However I want to zip the /build project and upload it to my server, however when I run:
`git archive --format=zip HEAD ./build > deploy.zip` I get an error message:
"fatal: current working directory is untracked"

I've tried:

1. using a more generic `zip -r ./deploy.zip . -x "**node_modules**"` - this works however I'm wondering if there's a way to use the `git archive` command instead?
2. using the --add-file option e.g. `git archive --format=zip --add-file=build/ HEAD ./build/ > deploy.zip`

Comment: as far as "including the `build/` directory" goes : your build directory is not tracked in git (that's a reasonable way to proceed with an artifacts directory), so it makes sense to use a non git command to include that directory in an archive.

Comment: as far as what you want to put in deploy.zip : I'm not sure I understood what you are looking for. Do you want to include both the original source files and the `build/` directory ? or just the `build/` directory ?

Comment: @LeGEC - I'm only trying to include the contents of the `build/` directory in the output zip file (i.e. excluding the original source).

It might not be possible to do this using `git archive` - the reason I want to use it is because the `git` functions tend to be installed on all systems (CI/ local/ remote/ server etc) - so it avoids having to establish a new process of installing a `zip` library on different deployment devices

Comment: do you deploy that archive yourself ? or do you intend to distribute it ? what platforms/OS do you have in mind ?

Comment: I deploy via the CI (github actions) to a load balanced AWS Elastic Beanstalk Linux 2 environment running Apache. The zip file is uploaded to S3 where EB serves it as a stateless file system for scaling/ recovery/ initialisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `build/` directory is not versioned in git (note: which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do), it makes sense to use a non git command to create an archive with that content.

You worded, in your comment, your concerns with using a standard command : I would argue that creating a `.zip` or `.tar.gz` file is even "more" standard. `git` simply relies on these standards (and specific libraries that implement them).

Comment: I'll accept this for now, was hoping to get `git archive` working but my understanding is that it's not possible in the way I want, so a standard `zip` library is needed